# where do objects, static, and constant variables live in php?

Tags: php

where do objects, static, and constant variables live in php?

I'm worried if I declare too many static/constants, would result to a memory leak.

thank you.

best regards,
bhadz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should worry about this only if you have a script that continuously works for days or weeks. If you run your scripts using apache's `mod_rewrite` - don't bother yourself by such questions
2. PHP manages everything related to memory automatically, in 99.9% cases you shouldn't care of it

Answer (score 0):

When working with PHP you usually work with modules of a web server. This means that the script is sort of sandboxed and there are no risks (every single run of the script will just end itself in a short and release everything that it is associated with it).

When working in CLI mode you can have issues only if you are working with long lasting executions (and you probably won't).

To answer your specific question I don't know the internals of PHP but almost all interpreters have a heap in which they store allocated objects so I guess that PHP is not an exception.